# Codename One - BrowserComponent: custom user-agent

Tags: codenameone

I've read the BrowserComponent API, but I didn't find any setUserAgent() method. How can I force the BrowserComponent to use a custom user-agent string?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really documented since it isn't supported everywhere but should work fine on Android and iOS. This should work:

```
browserComponent.setProperty("useragent", yourUserAgentHere);
```

Comment: It works fine on my (old) Android device (4.1.2), but it could be very useful for my app development to change the user-agent also of the Codename One simulator. Is it possible? Thank you.

Comment: You can file an RFE. I think this isn't there because it was missing from Java when we built the feature and was only added with Java 8. Since this has changed by now we can probably implement this

Comment: Thank you. Does RFE mean "request a feature"? Where can I do the request, in the Codename One GitHub repository, issues page? https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues

Comment: Yes. Just file an issue, the convention is to write `RFE: Description of rfe` in the title of the issue but you can use any common convention