# How can I request a desktop site from a Codename One Browser Component?

Tags: codenameone

I'm designing an app which has an embedded page on a form, using a BrowserComponent. Unfortunately the maintainer of the website recently created a very unfriendly "mobile friendly" version of the page and the user experience is much better with the desktop site.

Is there some way to get the BrowserComponent to request the desktop site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the user agent to match the one of a desktop browser see [Codename One - BrowserComponent: custom user-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786836/codename-one-browsercomponent-custom-user-agent/45789391)

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the prompt reply!<br/>
I've gotten it working with

pageBrowser.setProperty("useragent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.45 Safari/535.19");
<br/>
Though the iOS version of the app seems a little persnickety about showing me the desktop page still. I wonder if I have to use a mac specific useragent string when on iOS

Comment: Make sure to set the user agent String before adding the `BrowserComponent`. It won't change after the fact.

Comment: So an interesting problem that I surprisingly didn't notice. This does, indeed, set the user-agent string to what I ask it to be. However, that does not seem sufficient to request a mobile site, even from websites that my regular phone browser can request a mobile site from (and I therefore presume the site is not simply using a layout that responds to a smaller viewport). Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Unless perhaps my phone browser is emulating a larger viewport.

That sounds like a new inquiry so I'll move it to a new thread.

Thank you for the help, Shai.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible