# How can I set the BrowserComponent Browser Window Size in Codenameone

Tags: java, browser, codenameone

Certain websites have responsive CSS that lays out the site differently for a smaller screen. Other sites seem to serve different data when given different size data from the browser. When I request a desktop site with my phone browser, in addition to changing the user-agent (which has been described in [Codename One - BrowserComponent: custom user-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786836/codename-one-browsercomponent-custom-user-agent/45789391)) my phone also changes the apparent browser window size that it sends to the server and uses to display the webpage.

How can I change the apparent window size of a Codenameone Browser Component?

I think a followup question might be if there is a list of valid properties I can set on the Browser Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shai (the lord of codenameone) has pointed out, there isn't a way to do this natively.

However, CodenameOne BrowserComponents allow you to inject javascript into pages very easily, and you can use this to modify the parts of the webpage restricting zooming and restricting the size of the viewport.

Of course, this will still likely behave differently from the usual desktop site, but if the main things you are concerned about are restricted zoom and the restricted size of the viewport, you can use the following workaround.

Define the javascript somewhere:

```
    public static final String VIEWPORT_SCRIPT = "viewport = document.querySelector(\"meta[name=viewport]\");\r\n" + 
            "viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=1920px, height=1920px, initial-scale=0.25, maximum-scale=4.0, user-scalable=1');";
```

and when you initialize your BrowserComponent, give it an ActionListener that runs this script on load like so:

```
    pageBrowser = new BrowserComponent();

    pageBrowser.addWebEventListener(BrowserComponent.onLoad, (e) -> {
        pageBrowser.execute(VIEWPORT_SCRIPT);
    });
```

You can obviously play with the width and height you set in the javascript, as well as the initial zoom factor and zoom restriction.

The mechanics of the javascript are relatively simple, they search for the meta tag containing viewport characteristics, and set the content to be something else. If you inspect the html of the website you are trying to get a desktop version of, you may find other meta tags that you can mess around with for other behavior that I have not anticipated.

Hopefully this helps anyone else with the same problem. It was the best workaround I could find.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to that natively without physically making the web view larger than the screen. I think the support for desktop site in the native browsers has some special case code within it as they work with the underlying engine directly.

Comment: That is rather unfortunate. I think I've actually find a workaround and I hear self-answered questions are good so I'll put it in an answer. Thanks for the help!