# Codename one: Web view appears on Iphone, but not android

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

I have an app in codename one, both in Android and IOS.
However, a specific web view page appears only in IOS but not in android, as i run it in both of them.

-The page appears in browser as well, so i was not able to derive the problem, as no error appears in build. 
-I tried putting other pages, it works normally.
-I tried navigating in the specific page from other pages, it would not allow to load the page.

Page appears as blank in simulator.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any logs?

Comment: No error, so no logs. Just blank screen when opening the page in android, and page opens normally in IOS

Comment: Make sure the size of the component is large enough in runtime. Try setting the user agent of the browser to see if that impacts anything https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786836/codename-one-browsercomponent-custom-user-agent/45789391